# How to use Microsoft bot framework to send audio to user through facebook messenger (C#)

Tags: c#, audio, botframework, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

How to use microsoft bot framework to send audio to user through facebook messenger. I cannot use the richcard to send it out, or I did something wrong, please help me solve the problems.

Comment: Adaptive cards support audio sending???

Comment: No they can't sorry about that.

Comment: is there any method that can send audio from chatbot to the user

Answer (score 1):

In Bot Framework **Rich cards** can be used to send audio card. They can be send as an attachment to the user.

**Root Dialog**

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
        var reply = context.MakeMessage();
        reply.Attachments.Add(GetAudioCard());
        await context.PostAsync(reply);
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}


private static Attachment GetAudioCard()
{
    var audioCard = new AudioCard
    {
        Title = "Havana",
        Subtitle = "Camila Cabello",
        Image = new ThumbnailUrl
        {
            Url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havana_(Camila_Cabello_song)#/media/File:Havana_(featuring_Young_Thug)_(Official_Single_Cover)_by_Camila_Cabello.png"
        },
        Media = new List<MediaUrl>
        {
            new MediaUrl()
            {
                Url = "http://213.32.113.82/music/Now%20Thats%20What%20I%20Call%20Running%20(2018)/CD1/02.%20Camila%20Cabello%20feat.%20Young%20Thug%20-%20Havana.mp3"
            }
        },
        Buttons = new List<CardAction>
        {
            new CardAction()
            {
                Title = "Read More",
                Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                Value = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havana_(Camila_Cabello_song)"
            }
        }
    };
    return audioCard.ToAttachment();
}
```

Comment: But seems like Facebook messenger do not support audioCard to have Media

Comment: What did you try? What kind of error are you getting? See https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-RichCards#audio-card-1